# Submitting two forms in one button - Yii FrameWork

Tags: yii

I am trying to submit more than two forms in one button by using JS, how could i proceed to do this for yii active forms.

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to Yii. You can handle this using javacript. Write a function for on click event of the submit button. serialize the form1, serialize the form2. Concatenate two serialize results and pass it to an ajax request.

```
$('your_submit_button_selector').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
   formData = $('your_form1_selector').serialize()+$('your_form2_selector').serialize();
   $.ajax({
       url: submitUrl,
       data: formData,
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(data) {
        ...
       }
  }); 
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use this way...

```
jQuery('#yourForm1').submit();
jQuery('#yourForm2').submit();
```

Good Luck.